# How to change shortcut target

Tags: vbscript, shortcut-file

How do I change shortcut target using VBScript?
I tried

```
Set sh = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
Set shortcut = 
sh.CreateShortcut("%systemdrive%\users\%username%\Desktop\Audacity.ink")
shortcut.TargetPath = "%systemdrive%\users\%username%\Desktop\example.exe"
shortcut.Save
```

Comment: There shouldn't be a linebreak between `Set shortcut =` and `sh.CreateShortcut()`, and the extension is `.lnk`, not `.ink`.